# UIApp is nil which means we cannot dispatch control actions to their targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was changing file from one module to another, doing so I start getting this error in one of my tests. While earlier it was working absolutely fine.

[Assert] UIApp is nil which means we cannot dispatch control actions to their targets. If this assert is hit, we probably got here without UIApplicationMain() being executed, which likely means this code is not running in an app (perhaps a unit test being run without a host app) and will not work as expected.

In code add button in viewDidLoad()

```
    private lazy var button: ABCTypeButton = {
        let button = ABCTypeButton(title: viewModel.title, buttonType: .Payment).withAutoLayout()
        button.accessibilityLabel = viewModel.title
        button.accessibilityIdentifier = "paymentButton"
        button.resetTintColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ABCViewController.action1), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ABCViewController.action2), for: .touchDown)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ABCViewController.action3), for: [.touchUpOutside, .touchDragExit])
        return button
    }()

@objc private func action1() {
// code
}

public class ABCTypeButton: UIControl {

let iconImageView = UIImageView()
let buttonTitleLabel = UILabel()
private let chevronImageView = UIImageView(image: Icon.navigateNext.image)
private let stackView = UIStackView().withAutoLayout()

public init(title buttonTitle: String,
            buttonType: FeeButtonType,
            height: CGFloat = Spacing.four) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    setupViews(buttonTitle, buttonType: buttonType)
    setupConstraints(height: height)
} 
}
```

Trying to tap button from tests.

```
    func test() {
    let viewController = ViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
    let button = viewController.view.findViewByIdentifier("paymentButton") as! ABCTypeButton
    // I Checked that button is not nil
    button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    XCTAssertEqual(viewController.value, button.accessibilityIdentifier)
}
```

Target method action1() is not getting called

Comment: Can you Post ABCTypeButton class. and button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside) code. Above code it is not clear

Comment: Why would you call `sendActions` in a unit test? That’s a UI test. There is no point testing `sendActions`, we know what it does. Test your units in a unit test, not your interface behavior. If you want to test what happens when you tap a button, use a UI test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just ran into this, and made this rough extension for the touchUpInside event. can obviously be refactored to take in whatever events you'd like to call.

```
extension UIButton {
  public func touchUpInside(forTarget target: UIViewController) {
    guard let action = actions(forTarget: target, forControlEvent: .touchUpInside)?.first else {
      assertionFailure("could not find touchUpInside action for target")
      return
    }

    target.perform(Selector(action))
  }
}
```

Comment: Moving the code to a module makes the test part of a framework and not an app, so the UIApp part will actually be nil and we wont get any button press resulting in an automatic call of its target (which is done by an app type of bundle, but not by a framework type of bundle)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you asked this question 3 years ago, but maybe my answer will be helpful for somebody.
So, I did exactly what was said in the message `perhaps a unit test being run without a host app`.
To change this you need to go `Test_Target` -> `General` -> `Host Application`[image]